# How to generate cucumber reports not using a test runner

Tags: cucumber

I have created an application which runs cucumber tests on demand

Previously I was running cucumber through a test runner in junit, but I now run the tests using cucumbers own `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main`.

Is there a way to use cucumber plugin "pretty" to generate cucumber reports with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `-p "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"` to your options . See [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-cucumber-optionsclasspath-tag-glue-pretty-and-monochrome-cucumberapiclimainmain-method-when).